# React hook form pass errors to child component (TS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Cant get error validation to work in child component. I've watched the [multistep tutorial video](http://youtube.com/watch?v=CeAkxVwsyMU&t=511s) but I believe it's out of date with the latest version (perhaps I'm wrong).

I have a parent component in which I instantiate the methods, it contains one field and then a component:

```
const OD= () => {
    const methods = useForm();
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = methods;

    return (
        <FormProvider {...methods} >
           <Field>
              <Label>Complaint:<span className="mandatory">*</span></Label>
              <Textarea {...register("Complaint", { required: true })}/>                  
              {errors.Complaint && <RequiredMessage/>}
           </Field> 
           <Allergens />
        </FormProvider>
    )
}
```

Inside my component I then have the following:

```
const Allergens = () => {
    const { register, formState: { errors } } = useFormContext();
    return(
        <Label>Allergy<span className="mandatory">*</span></Label>
        <Input {...register("Allergy")} />
        {errors.Allergy&& <RequiredMessage/>}
    )
}
```

The register works fine and I can see it collecting data from the parent and child component, the errors work fine on the parent but not on the child (allergens).

I have no syntax errors, is there anything im missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What errors do you expect on the child component? Looks like you're not passing any validation options in `<Input {...register("Allergy")} />`

Comment: Oh yeah! That's it, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a mistake. Inside of `Allergens` component input you registered the input like `{...register(("Allergy"))}`. You used double brackets, Remove one of them. What is actually need is `{...register("Allergy")}`.

Comment: Hi Muhammed, that's probably correct but it still works, as mentioned the issue is that the error is not validating on the child component input.